# Is it Safe to Share the Wallet Keystore File Without Password?

Tags: security, private-key, keystore, attacks

There is an ICO that asks for ethereum keystore file, which is unusual for me as far as ICOs go. Even though it does not looks like it contains private key and password it still feels unsettling.
Is it not private, can it be shared safely?

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you share which ICO is it?

Comment: During https://polkadot.network auction they ask to either Load an Ethereum JSON Keystore File or Generate a new Ethereum wallet

Comment: (Disclaimer: This in no way should be considered legal advice. Moreover, nothing written here should be construed as investment advice either)
I recently participated in the ICO. Yes, it's true they ask for the JSON keystore file, but they also allow you to generate a new wallet with them.
I wouldn't fear it is a scam in the sense they will run with the money by emptying your wallet, but I wouldn't give them my JSON Keystore File. 
You could create a wallet with them and just use it for this particular ICO if you are interested in investing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should definitely not give away your keystore file as it contains your encrypted private key. The only thing that can decrypt your private key is your password. However, one could perform a brute force algorithm on your keystore file in an attempt to crack your password and gain access to all your funds.

If you create a new wallet on [myetherwallet.com](https://myetherwallet.com) it explicitly states that you should not share your keystore file.

Comment: Or create a new wallet with low cash flow.

Comment: But let's say your password is somenting like `xD09@ˆ@ˆ@dd012##0123[s--D]dks__!` and the and someone try to performe a brute force on the keystore. According with https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm it can take centuries to crack the password, does it make sense ?

Comment: @EduardoPereira I think they are just opportunistically trying to steal your wallet. If your wallet has such long and random password, the chances are that they will never get your money but still not a good idea to pass keystore files around.